# Where will the incident with the sudo command be reported to?

Tags: terminal, sudo

If a non-admin types a sudo command in Terminal, this will appear after they enter their password:

`User is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.`

Where is this reported to?

Comment: Mandatory xkcd reference: http://xkcd.com/838/

Comment: It's always irritated me to no end that sudo is so crabby in responding to almost always perfectly innocent errors.

Comment: /var/spool/mail/<USERNAME>

source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546933/where-are-sudo-incidents-reported

Comment: to the POLICE! hahahaha ;-)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The event will be logged in `/var/log/secure.log` and a mail will be sent to root (which by default goes to `/dev/null` which is Unix speak for it is discarded).

Comment: +1 Sending the mail shouldn't fail, but probably won't be read. It is possible to have it sent to a different user, but the chances of that modification are about the same as someone reading root's mail.

Comment: I had a look at the log file in the mean time, mail to root goes to /dev/null.

Answer (score 5):

> In older versions of OS X (through 10.6 or maybe 10.7), the disallowed sudo attempt would be logged in `/var/log/secure.log`; in more recent versions it's recorded in the ASL (Apple System Log) database, in `/var/log/asl/*`. You can read this with the `Console.app` utility (select `ALL MESSAGES` in the sidebar, then if you can't find them use the search field in the upper right to search for `sudo`). You can also use the command-line `syslog` command to query the database (`syslog -k Facility authpriv -k Sender sudo` should do it). Note that with either Console.app or `syslog`, the entries will only be visible if you are running as an admin or root.

[Source](https://superuser.com/a/676968/235569)

Comment: "Note that with either Console.app or syslog, the entries will only be visible if you are running as an admin or root." @Braiam does that mean I could run the above command with `sudo` if I'm in the sudoers file? Like: `sudo syslog -k Facility authpriv -k Sender sudo`

Comment: @AlexIxeras well, sudo makes you effectively root.

Answer (score -2):

it will be emailed to their apple id, i have found

Comment: *Who's* AppleID? There could be many AppleIDs associated with many users on one OS X machine.